# What is the Proptype for HTMLDocument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a prop that accepts `window.document`

```
<MyComponent container={document} />
```

How should this proptype be defined?

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  container: Proptypes.????.isRequired
};
```

Comment: could it be element? (educated guess at best) but maybe?

Comment: @promisified: tried it.  no dice  :(

Answer (score 2):

Ah!  the following works using `instanceOf`...

```
container: PropTypes.instanceOf(HTMLDocument).isRequired
```

**Update**

'HTMLDocument' does not work in IE10.

If you need to support IE10 you can use

```
PropTypes.instanceOf(Document)
```

As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), the abstract interface [HTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument) extends the [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) interface.

Comment: Did you try `PropTypes.node`?

Comment: "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop of type `HTMLDocument`, expected instance of `HTMLDocument`." in Chrome... nice and helpful error message!